# How to simulate node joins and failures with a local Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm developing a Kubernetes scheduler and I want to test its performance when nodes join and leave a cluster, as well as how it handles node failures.

What is the best way to test this locally on Windows 10?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a vm and join ????

Comment: Using VirtualBox perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I should've clarified that I'm running a local cluster with Docker Desktop. I'm looking to add/remove nodes to this cluster to test my scheduler's performance.

Is creating VMs (e.g. with VirtualBox) an appropriate solution? I'm not quite sure how this would work...

Comment: You may try microk8s. It uses multipass to create vm. Choose tiniest images for worker node. But still resource intensive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't add nodes to Docker Desktop with Kubernetes enabled. Docker Desktop is single-node only.

I can think of two possible solutions, off the top of my head:

- You could use any of the cloud providers. Major (AWS, GCP, Azure) ones have some kind of free tier (under certain usage, or timed). Adding nodes in those environments is trivial.
- Create local VM for each node. This is less than perfect solution - very resource intesive. To make adding nodes easier, you could use [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) to provision your cluster.